# How to import SVG icons to Sketch so that they don't overlap and placed in order?

Tags: icon, svg, sketch-app

I've downloaded an icon set which has a folder containing SVG icons. When I select and drag the SVG files into Sketch, all icons are placed very close to each others so I'm ordering all of them by hand.

[image]

If there is a way to order them automatically, I'll be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If your icons are grouped (i.e. each icon is a group separate from the rest), you can just select all icons and arrange them with the make grid command (arrange-->make grid ) there you can choose the numer of rows and columns and the spacing you want between icons.

See a more detailed [make grid example](http://www.sketchtips.info/articles/make-grid-part-1).

Comment: One thing to note, if you do have your svgs arranged by name in the folder, and then select all and drag in, when you make the grid, it will keep them in the proper order.

Answer (score 2):

You could import your SVGs to the [IcoMoon app](https://icomoon.io/app) to generate a sprite (in SVG) to open in Sketch.

After importing your SVGs, press the "Generate SVG..." button at the bottom left corner. Press "Preferences" and check "Include Tiles (CSS Sprite)" and download your set.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2018, there's a plugin to do exactly what you want. Takes a bunch of external SVGs, and places them each in an artboard, arranged in a grid. will even add a mask & color fill if you want to do symbol overrides. The plugin is the [Sketch Icons](https://github.com/AMoreaux/Sketch-Icons) plugin ([detailed instructions here](https://blog.prototypr.io/introducing-sketch-icons-2074d9dc9ed2)).

[image]